# Using-declaration of an existing namespace type vs creating a type alias

Tags: c++, typedef, type-alias, using-declaration

This is not a question about the difference between `using` and `typedef` for creating type aliases. I would like to provide access to an existing type from a namespace inside a code block or a function.

I found two different ways :

I can "include" the type with a using declaration :

```cpp
using typename mynamespace::mytype;
```

Or I can create a type alias :

```cpp
typedef mynamespace::mytype mytype;
using mytype = mynamespace::mytype; //C++11
```

1. Is there any difference ?
2. What are the pros and cons of each syntax ?
3. Which one is the most used/recommended ?

Thank you.

Related question : [Using-declaration of an existing type from base class vs creating a type alias inside child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449034/using-declaration-of-an-existing-type-from-base-class-vs-creating-a-type-alias-i)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any difference ?

A type alias for a name in a *namespace* can appear in a class

```
struct S { using mytype = mynamespace::mytype; };
```

while a using-declaration may not.

> What are the pros and cons of each syntax ?

The previous point is a pretty big con if you are dealing with class scope.

Other than that the two approaches are pretty much similar. An alias is a new name that stands exactly for the type that is aliased. While a using declaration brings the existing name of the type into scope. If you use `mytype` for both, you won't notice a difference.

> Which one is the most used/recommended ?

I doubt there's consensus on this. Use the one you have to when you have to (class scope), but stick to your team's style guide otherwise.

Comment: ```struct test : base { using typename base::mytype; };``` can also be used.

Comment: @Baptistou - Your question was about namespaces, I answer in accordance to that.

Comment: @Baptistou - Don't. Editing and invalidating existing answers is poor netiquette on SO. You can always ask another

Comment: Ok I will do that and link to this post.

Comment: @Baptistou - Good call! That's how one creates a useful library of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered another difference between the two syntaxes : it is not possible to define a type alias with the same name as an existing namespace in the same scope.

```cpp
namespace name1 {
    struct name2 {};
}

namespace name2 {
    struct name3 {};
}

//error: 'typedef struct name1::name2 name2' redeclared as different kind of symbol
/* typedef name1::name2 name2; */

//OK
using typename name1::name2;

//error: 'name2' does not name a type
/* name2 val1 = {}; */

//OK disambiguation with keyword "struct"
struct name2 val2 = {};

//OK namespace qualifier with "::"
name2::name3 val3 = {};

int main(){
    //OK different scope
    typedef name1::name2 name2;
    name2 val = {};
}
```